# Number not showing in HTML Select Box

Tags: html, wordpress

I have a system on my website here: https://counterboosting.com/asasdasdasd/

And there is supposed to be a number in the select box under "Select number of wins" but only a few pixels of it is visible for some reason. How can I change the width or make the 1 show up?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the css width property; [image: DevTools]

Comment: <select id="sNumber" name="current_tier_num"  style="width:100px;padding:5px;">

I put that, but it didn't change anything. Is something wrong?

Comment: try adding `!important`;  `<select id="sNumber" name="current_tier_num" style="width:100px !important;padding:5px;">`

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

The padding of input-lg class is the reason of this problem.

Comment: <select id="sNumber" name="current_tier_num"  style="width:170px;padding:5px;">

Comment: Please add code to show what you're recommending as a solution

Comment: I can not now because the website is down. Simply saing, the padding value specified in the css was to big. Nothing special.